# Is it possible to backup across multiple hard drives?

Tags: backup, raid, zfs

I'm going to be setting up an 8x20TB ZFS RaidZ2 with no spare. This will give me roughly 100TB of storage for large 3D model files.

I want to purchase some extra HDDs so I can periodically backup and store this data off-site. While I could buy an extra 8x20TB and use dd to copy the drives, it would be nice if I could copy the data to 5x20TB drives instead.

I'd like to do this without building a separate computer to do so. I was thinking I could connect the backup drives over USB (slow is ok). Is there good software or a method I can use to copy across multiple disks? If it's possible, I would like to avoid a situation where I don't have enough total space across the backup drives due to file-by file copy leaving too much "slack" on each of the drives when a file is too big to fit but there's still usable space on the drive.

If this idea is totally moronic, I'm open to others, but I would like to avoid cloud providers yearly fees. I'm a one man shop, not a mega-corp.

Comment: Do you want to have to backup on each disks or do you want to have a sort of pool of disks where there is some abstraction. Like Backup - > Pool - > Disk 1,2,3 and where you can add disks in the future if needed

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, I'm sorry. I want to make sure I have a copy of my data backed up that I can store somewhere else physically. I was thinking that doing a file based backup might save me the cost of 3x drives.

Comment: You can have a backup solution where you place the backup on all three disk or you can have make a volume of all those three disks and backup to that volume. Backup solutions also have deduplication (Google that please), which also can reduce the size of the backup. I would recommend creating a volume because that gives you the flexibility in the future to add disks if needed.An alternative would be if you are open to it, to backup to the cloud then you can have things like immutable storage (good for security). Instead of a computer you could also consider a NAS.(like QNAP)

Comment: Data deduplication involves identifying and eliminating duplicate or redundant data within a dataset to save storage space

Answer (score -1):

I would create a lvm volume group where you add the disks to, that gives you the ability to add disks later if desired.

And then backup with a script or a open source backup solution like bacula.